# 'this.get_element() is undefined' when using UpdateProgress ASP.NET AJAX

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax

I'm getting a JavaScript error in the ASP.NET AJAX framework when using the UpdateProgress control.

Details:

1. The UpdateProgress is inside the UpdatePanel.
2. Firebug error information:

   this.get_element() is undefined
   Sys$UI$_UpdateProgress$_startRequest()ScriptRe...373681250 (line 1931)
   anonymous()ScriptRe...373681250 (line 61)

**How do I resolve this issue?  Is this a known bug and if so what are the steps I need to do to avoid it?  Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this same problem before, but I don't quite remember how I solved it. I think it is a timing issue when using the DisplayAfter property (so yes, probably a bug).
Try setting DisplayAfter to 0 and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Many problems with the update panel are caused by invalid html. Can you check your page's generated html for errors in a [html validator](http://validator.w3.org/)?
Can you also post the whole JavaScript function or code in which the error occurred so we can determine what `this` is in the case?